# How to glue HDPE plastic to concrete blocks?

Tags: concrete, outdoor, adhesive, plastic, concrete-block

I am using PL 500 to glue concrete bricks to each other. I need to line the back of the brick wall with some high-density polyethylene (HDPE) plastic tarps for water-proofing. The PL 500 says it will not work on plastic. Is there a glue suitable for gluing the HDPE plastic to the concrete? This is used outdoors, so must be waterproof glue, or at least once it is finished drying, able to survive winter, rain, and storms.

Comment: A quick search shows epoxies are recommended for plastic <> concrete bonding. Is this for a permanent installation of a tarp against a concrete wall? You'll likely find there are better materials than tarps to use for waterproofing concrete.

Comment: Waterproof cement on the face side?

Comment: Will the plastic be exposed to the sun?

Comment: PL300 is for foam plastic insulation to concrete. Don't know if it would work for HDPE or not - few things stick to that stuff. As already commented, there are plenty of solutions to waterproof concrete that are **not** tarps. Y'know, actual solutions suitable for things built from concrete and put out in the weather....